# Can hotshot be used in multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, profiling, profiler, profile

I have a long-running multithreaded program, and I'd like to occasionally like to call a function with [Profile.runcall](http://docs.python.org/library/hotshot.html#hotshot.Profile.runcall) and dump the data to a file.

The [hotshot documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/hotshot.html) states: `Note: The hotshot profiler does not yet work well with threads. It is useful to use an unthreaded script to run the profiler over the code you’re interested in measuring if at all possible.`

However, I've test having multiple threads profile a function simultaneously, and I've encountered no problems.  In my case, the functions being profiled are all self-contained and do not spawn any additional threads during execution.  And I make sure that every `Profile` object has its own file so that they don't clobber each other.

So my guess is that the warning about multiple threads means that I would have problems if the function being profiled spawned additional threads itself.  When I profile a test function that does spawn other threads, the spawned threads are not profiled.  However, this still doesn't seem to cause any problems, since the function being profiled seems to work just fine.

Can someone confirm or refute that hotshot is safe to run in a multithreaded program?  I don't want to deploy something that might crash later, even if it seems to pass my initial tests.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't confirm -- there are possible race conditions that may happen very rarely (when hotshot's running on multiple threads at the same time) but could cause false answers (I don't think they could cause crashes, but I'm not 100% positive) when they do. Only careful code inspection of hotshot's sources (and possible strategic insertion of some lock acquire/release) can reassure you that such race conditions can't EVER happen in your use case.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the input.  I guess I'll just make sure that this is turned off in production unless I get a more definitive answer.

Comment: "does not yet work well" may just mean it's less accurate when running with threads. You should see if you can find who wrote that and see if they can tell you better what it means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, we have a setting in [CubicWeb](http://www.cubicweb.org) (which uses multiple threads) to enable hotshot profiling, and so far I've never experienced issues when enabling profiling.